# Check if document contains a class similar to the specified string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find all elements that contain 'ad'.

Such as:

```html
<iframe class="container" /> <!-- False -->
<a class="adp" /> <!-- True -->
<a class="adleft" /> <!-- True -->
<a class="some-other-class" /> <!-- False -->
```

Could I use a `forEach`?
I appreciate any help from everyone.

Comment: I see you tagged CSS but hinted at using JavaScript. Can you clarify? Are you looking for a CSS solution or a JavaScript solution?

Comment: What would you be looping over with your forEach()?

Comment: @Wyck It suggested I used the tag. If it causes problems, I shall remove it. It is, though, focused around javascript, though I am open to CSS answers as well if necessary.

Comment: @user1599011 It would check if it contains that class, and if so, removes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with the combination of [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) by using the `[attr*=value]` syntax.

The above attribute selector syntax will work like:

> Represents elements with an attribute name of `attr` whose `value` contains at least one occurrence of `value` within the string.

The outcome combination of above solution will be something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class*='ad']");
```

Which give you all the elements whose contain *ad* within their class names. Then you can simply use a simple loop or array helper like [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to use the outcome. Note that the previous outcome will produce an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which needs to convert into an array before using array helpers, otherwise you can use the traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop over it.

Here how the final code should look like:

```js
const ads = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='ad']");

Array.from(ads).forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
})
```

```html
<iframe class="container"></iframe>
<a class="adp"></a>
<a class="adleft"></a>
<a class="some-other-class"></a>
```

**NOTE:** You always need to properly open and close HTML tags especially `iframe`. Since it is not assumed as a self-closing tag it will lead to invalid HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector to get every elements containing ad. You can read more about it here : [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[class*="ad"]');
```

Comment: This could also be considered an answer. 1+!